# WPF, C#: How to handle an event raised from dynamically created user controls

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, user-controls, event-handling

Basically I have two main components to my program.
1) I have my main window which contains my dynamically created user controls.
2) The two different types of user controls.(ctr1 and ctr2)
I want to be able to press a button on ctr1, have it bubble up an event and have the main window handle the event which will create another instance of ctr2. The problem I am having is that I honestly can't find any good resources that gives actual code examples of how to accomplish this.

In ctr1 I have:

```
    public event RoutedEventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { AddHandler(MyEvent_randomName, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(MyEvent_randomName, value); }
    }

    void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ctr1.MyEvent_randomName);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }
    protected override void RaiseEvent_click()
    {
        RaiseMyEvent();
    }
```

and for my mainWindow I have:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindow.AddHandler(ctr1.MyEvent_randomName, new RoutedEventHandler(MyButtonHandler));

    }
    void MyButtonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("My New Clicked Event");
    }
```

Where I have been running into trouble is the "MainWindow.AddHandler(ctr1.MyEvent_random......);
I keep getting the error:
*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.UIElement.AddHandler(System.Windows.RoutedEvent, System.Delegate)'*

Im sorry if this is a very beginner question but I only started WPF and C# a few days ago and I have yet to find a good online tutorial that explains everything plainly.

Comment: The code I have above was a quick copy paste. I am actually a little embarrassed I didn't look at it properly. "RaiseEvent_click()" should be "OnClick()" for one.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'System.Windows.UIElement.AddHandler(System.Windows.RoutedEvent,
>   System.Delegate)'

You are trying to access the method statically:

> MainWindow.AddHandler . . .

When you should be doing:

```
AddHandler . . .
```

As an aside you may want to look at ICommand and MVVM to do what you want to do, but as a beginner you have a lot to learn right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

In ctr1

```
public event EventHandler Ctrl1ClickEvent;
```

when you press the button in ctrl1

```
Ctrl1ClickEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

In mainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.ctrl1.Ctrl1ClickEvent  += ctrl1ClickHandler;

}

private void ctrl1ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("My New Clicked Event");
}
```